# Parallel processing of large number of processes

Tags: c#, process, parallel-processing, threadpool

I use a `ThreadPool` to execute several processes in parallel, like shown [here](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/8a6ce546-6516-46c7-9398-edc0d28a38f1/)
with a difference that I start my own process/program with some parameters. In few words, this program calculates some values and write them into a text file, which I compare afterwards.

```
public void StartProcess()
{
    string par = @"-p ""foo"" -c 17";
    Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\MyProgramm.exe", par); 
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
}

void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    // Indicates that the process has been completed
    this.doneEvent.Set();
    Console.WriteLine("thread {0} end...", ThreadIndex);
}
```

For a small number of threads it works fine. In my case I must start about 200 threads, but in `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method I get a `NotSuppotedException`

> The number of objects in waitHandles is greater than the system
>   permits.

My question now is: Is there a possibility of `ThreadPool` class to manage a large number of threads? Something like a queue, starting new processes when other has been completed.
To be simple, in my case a process = thread.

Comment: Even of modern computer, running 200 programs simultaneously will take a longer time than running X program in parrallel (X equals to the number of logical processors). Do you actually need to run them all simultanously? Can't you simply use the TPL to queue the work?

Comment: Of course not, I only want the thread pool to manage the most efficient number of parallel jobs. Unfortunately, I use C# 2.0 and cannot use TPL

Answer (score 0):

Create a single field

```
private volatile int ProcessesStillRunning;
```

Before you start your processes, initialize it to the correct value

```
this.ProcessesStillRunning = 200;
this.StartProcesses(200);
// now wait on your doneEvent
```

Modify your handler to decrement this field once the process exits

```
if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.ProcessesStillRunning) == 0)
    this.doneEvent.Set();
```

Of course, you should now that your approach will not use any .NET built-in parallelism limits and will just run 200 processes. Then it is a matter of how the OS will handle this.